# Removing certain elements of array not working

Tags: php

i have this array, and all i want it to do is cycle through and just remove certain elements that appear in the if, however whenever i output the array it always just shows

```
array(0) { }
```

instead of

```
["addon_h_id"]=> string(1) "1"
```

Here is the code which cycles through it, if i remove this code then the array displays as normal

```
        foreach ($new_shopping_array as $columnName => $columnData) {
                          if($columnName == "s_list_id" || "user_id"){
                              unset($new_shopping_array[$columnName]);  
                          }        
                      }
```

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): You're doing $columnName = "s_list_id", then ORing the result of that against "user_id"

```
if($columnName == "s_list_id" || $columnName == "user_id"){
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `if` statement:

```
if($columnName == "s_list_id" || "user_id")
```

The string `"user_id"` will evaluate to true so all values will be removed.

You probably want something like:

```
if (in_array($columnName, array('s_list_id', 'user_id')))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($new_shopping_array as $columnName => $columnData) 
{
    if ($columnName != "s_list_id" && $columnName != "user_id")
    {
        $new_array[$columnName] = $columnData;
    }        
 }
```

$new_array contains the data you need.

If you prefer your solution you will need to alter the conditional a bit like so:

```
foreach ($new_shopping_array as $columnName => $columnData) 
{
    if ($columnName == "s_list_id" || $columnName == "user_id")
    {
        unset($new_shopping_array[$columnName]);
    }        
 }
```

The way it was written it told php that if `$columnName` is equal to `s_list_id` OR "user_id". The condition was not in the `columnName` and "user_id" validates as TRUE (since it has something in there). So your conditional was always TRUE thus removing everything from the original array.

HTH